# Alternatives to dragging formula down?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I'm having trouble applying the following formulas to entire columns in Google Sheets. I think that an array is the best option because there are 5000+ rows, but any help is appreciated. I'm really stuck.

1. `=(IF (K2<>"", K2, IF(Q2<>"", Q2, IF(T2<>"", T2, IF (W2<>"", W2, W2)))))`

   I tried: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF (K2<>"", K2, IF(Q2<>"", Q2, IF(T2<>"", T2, IF (W2<>"", W2, W2)))))`
2. `=(IF(A2=A1,C1+1,1))`

   I tried: `=ArrayFormula(IF(A2=A1,C1+1,1))`
3. `=if(C2="2019-January", "NEW")`
4. `=VLOOKUP(E2, $AA$2:$AA$13,1, false)`

Comment: `trouble applying` = ? What results if you drag one of those down and what is your desired outcome? In the example of `=VLOOKUP(E2, $AA$2:$AA$13,1, false)`, E2 should change to E3, E4, E5, etc.. are you not experiencing that?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @EricF thanks for replying! If I drag any of these formulas, they work, but it takes forever. I'll share a copy of the sheet with dummy data asap.

Comment: @user0 thanks! i will!

Answer (score 1):

## 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(K2:K&Q2:Q&T2:T&W2:W),
 IF(K2:K<>"", K2:K, 
 IF(Q2:Q<>"", Q2:Q, 
 IF(T2:T<>"", T2:T, 
 IF(W2:W<>"", W2:W, W2:W)))), ))
```

## 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=A1, C1+1, 1))
```




```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=A1, C1:C+1, 1))
```

## 3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TO_TEXT(C2:C)="2019-January", "NEW", ))
```

## 4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E, AA2:AA13, 1, 0)))
```